# How to convert "\uxxxx\uxxxx" to u'\Uxxxxxxxx'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, escaping, unicode-escapes

I have a text file who is filled with unicode characters as `"\ud83d\udca5"` but python don't seem to like them.
But if I replace it by `u'\U0001f4a5'` which seems to be his python escape style ([Charbase](http://www.charbase.com/1f4a5-unicode-collision-symbol)), it works.

Is there a solution to convert them all into the `u"\Uxxxxxxxx"` escape format than python can understand ?

Thanks.

Comment: That's because that's UTF-16, not UTF-8.

Comment: @Joey: That's not the (entire) point. There is a fundamental difference between a Unicode object and an encoded bytes sequence (encoded by UTF-16, UTF-8 or whatever else).

Comment: Yeah, I guess so but I have UTF-16 chars in an UTF-8 file.
That's the problem.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: My comment referred mostly to "I have this stuff in an UTF-8 file and it doesn't work properly"

Comment: Do you mean you have a file with literal backslashes and letter ‘u’s in? If so you need to work out what format it is and use a suitable parser for that. eg it might be JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up Unicode and encoded strings. `u'\U0001f4a5'` is a Unicode object, Python's internal datatype for handling strings. (In Python 3, the `u` is optional since now *all* strings are Unicode objects).

Files, on the other hand, use encodings. UTF-8 is the most common one, but it's just one means of storing a Unicode object in a byte-oriented file or stream. When opening such a file, you need to specify the encoding so Python can translate the bytes into meaningful Unicode objects.

In your case, it seems you need to open file using the `UTF-16` codec instead of `UTF-8`.

```
with open("myfile.txt", encoding="utf-16") as f:
    s = f.read()
```

will give you the proper contents if the codec is in fact `UTF-16`. If it doesn't look right, try `"utf-16-le"` or `"utf-16-be"`.

Comment: Well, I tried but when I'm opening the file with ```utf-16```, I have:  
```UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 9526-9527: illegal UTF-16 surrogate```.
Same with ```utf-16-be```, I can open it with ```utf-8``` but with the \uxxxx\uxxxx problem.

Comment: Then it's using a different encoding altogether. Unfortunately, there is no way to reliably determine that encoding - you need to check at the source of the file. Can you post a relevant sample of the file?